# Ruby getting undefined Method error, and i am not sure if i fully understand how methods are working for my plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, discourse

i am trying to create a plugin for Discourse, which is written in Ruby. As normal blank files my program is working perfect and without errors, but when i try to adapt my code into the plugin context i run into issues and i am not sure if i really understand how the whole idea with functions is meant to be. 
I thought it would be smart to have more than just one file, to outsource functionality in different methods and require them in a kind of "main" file. For example getting tweets is one method in an extra file, sending tweets a different method in another file. In blank ruby code its working fine but when i try to integrate that into the plugin file structure i get the error

```
undefined method `my_method' for #<Plugin::Instance:0x00007f9004012fc0> (NoMethodError)
```

the files with the methods are in a lib directory and the "main" file which is called the plugin.rb is in the mainfolder

so i tried

```
require_relative 'lib/my_method'
```

and the other way

```
require_relative File.expand_path('../lib/my_method.rb', __FILE__)
```

but i still run into that error.

i have not defined any kind of classes or modules or something like that so the "method files" are literally starting with

```
def self.my_method

    #my code here
    end
```

Could that be the reason why i run into the error above? Why is it working as blank ruby code, but not when i try to run the plugin with `rails s` on my discourse instance? 
I am still pretty new into ruby programming, so maybe my question seems a bit silly.

Here is the link which lead me threw the plugin creation:

https://meta.discourse.org/t/beginners-guide-to-creating-discourse-plugins-part-1/30515

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, your understanding of methods is shallow. Basically, any method you declare in the global scope is added to the Object class as private method, so it is accessible everywhere in your objects cause they derive from Object class and in global scope because it is the scope of the Object class. If you declare method as self.method, you make it a method of main Object, because self refers to main, which is not the desired behaviour for you. To fix that issue, you should just remove self and write it like that:

```
def my_method
end
```

This way this method will be added to the Object class itself, not the main Object. There is a [link](https://vitobotta.com/2013/09/13/top-level-methods-in-ruby/) on the article about methods in general. And another [one](https://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/what-is-the-ruby-top-level/) on the toplevel scope behaviour. In [this](https://repl.it/@artur_martsinko/GoldPhysicalTwintext) codepen you may observe the difference. Also, it may be useful for you to learn some Ruby before going on with your development. I suggest [rubymonk](https://rubymonk.com/). Another issue is your one-method files which is not the best practice for ruby code organization. Ruby is truly object-oriented language and if you need to have a bunch or even one general-purpose method, it is better to put it in a module or class to define its purpose and role in application, make it reusable and trackable, without global scope pollution.

Comment: Thanks that seems to fix it. I was pretty sure i tried that but seems like i was wrong! Thank you so much for your answer!